# Downloading PDFs that open in an Iframe

Tags: selenium, pdf, firefox, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate the downloading of some pdfs with Selenium (python bindings).  The problem is that  the pdf is dynamically generated on the server and embedded in an Iframe. I have tried several things, that were referred in similar questions, setting the following preferences:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
fp.set_preference("plugin.scan.Acrobat", "99.0")
fp.set_preference("plugin.scan.plid.all", False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = fp)
```

The problem seems to be that I'm getting "a plugin is needed to display this content" in the iframe in which the pdf is supposed to be embedded, when `("pdfjs.disabled", True)` is used. When it set to false the pdf does load, but doesn't download.

One other thing is that the file extension is capitalized, i.e. *.PDF